# Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I am writing one jdbc program where I got this problem:name is already used by existing          object.

```
 try
    {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    }

    catch(ClassNotFoundException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    Connection con=null;

    Statement stmt=null;

     con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","system","moon");

    stmt=con.createStatement();

     stmt.execute("create table emp4090(eno int,ename varchar(20))");

       System.out.println("Done successfully");
```

Error I am getting when I am running this program.

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object

at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:288)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:743)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:207)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:946)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1169)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeInternal(OracleStatement.java:1688)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute(OracleStatement.java:1654)
at com.aol.jdbc.Jdbc.main(Jdbc.java:26)
```

Comment: It appears the table `emp4090` already exists.

Comment: See [Oracle/PLSQL: ORA-00995 Error](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora00995.php).

Comment: I have already check this option dropping the table name but it is not working.

Comment: Why don't you just do this in sqlplus?  You say you can't drop the table, but don't show the error.

Answer (score 1):

Its simple, when you create the table once you cannot create her in the second time.
try to drop the table and then to recreate it.